# Error while processing json data in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am running a simple Pyspark program from this link-https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html I am facing issue while I'm trying to read the data from Global temporary view

```
sqlContext.sql("""select * from people""").show()


Hive history file=/tmp/sshuser/hive_job_log_sshuser_202004281336_882204804.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 353, in sql
    return self.sparkSession.sql(sqlQuery)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 716, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.getTimeVar(org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf$ConfVars, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit);'
```

But it works fine when I'm reading the data using dataframe operations:
[image]

Not sure what I'm missing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that there is an error in any of the yet unexecuted/unmaterialized transformations that define `people` table? Also, sqlContext is deprecated. Does using `spark.sql("""select * from people""")` also fail ?

Answer (score 0):

Try "select * from people" instead triple double quotes